# Find div with same text and click on it by click on div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can i trigger a click on the `div` (from time-table html block) with the exact same text of the `div` (from list-events html block) which i click on? (`jQuery`prefered )

**Note: IDs are unique.**

**Sample HTML Block:**

```
    <div id="list-events">  
    <div class="jqtl-event-node">             
        09.07.2022 / 16:00 One Way (ID 4178)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>                
    </div>
    <div class="jqtl-event-node">            
        12.07.2022 / 19:00 One Way (ID 4179)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>                
    </div>
    <div class="jqtl-event-node">            
        22.07.2022 / 11:00 One Way (ID 4180)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>                
    </div>
</div>

<div id="time-table">
    <div class="fc-title">            
        09.07.2022 / 16:00 One Way (ID 4178)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>                
    </div>
    <div class="fc-title">            
        12.07.2022 / 19:00 One Way (ID 4179)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>                
    </div>
    <div class="fc-title">            
        22.07.2022 / 11:00 One Way (ID 4180)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>                
    </div>  
</div>
```

**`div` i click on:**

```
    <div class="jqtl-event-node">             
        09.07.2022 / 16:00 One Way (ID 4178)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>                
    </div>
```

**`div` i try to trigger a click:**

```
    <div class="fc-title">            
        09.07.2022 / 16:00 One Way (ID 4178)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>                
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function matchedBy(elem) {
    //$(elem).data('id'); //Way 1, If you set the data to the element
    //$(elem).text().split('One Way')[0].trim(); //Way 2 for comparing datetime
    //$(elem).text().split('ID')[1].match(/\d+/)[0]; //Way 3 for comparing id
    return $(elem).text().split(')')[0].trim(); //as requested
}

$('#list-events').on('click', '.jqtl-event-node', function () {
    let thisText = matchedBy(this);
    let matched = $('#time-table .fc-title').toArray().filter(a => matchedBy(a) === thisText);
    if (matched.length > 0) {
        $(matched[0]).click();
    }
});

$('#time-table').on('click', '.fc-title', function () {
    console.log('clicked', this)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list-events">
    <div class="jqtl-event-node">
        09.07.2022 / 16:00 One Way (ID 4178)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="jqtl-event-node">
        12.07.2022 / 19:00 One Way (ID 4179)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="jqtl-event-node">
        22.07.2022 / 11:00 One Way (ID 4180)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="time-table">
    <div class="fc-title">
        09.07.2022 / 16:00 One Way (ID 4178)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fc-title">
        12.07.2022 / 19:00 One Way (ID 4179)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fc-title">
        22.07.2022 / 11:00 One Way (ID 4180)<span class="driver-name">hasan</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx - is it possible to compare the ids only? these are unique

Comment: @evavienna, Yes, It is possible... If you can store the id in 'jqtl-event-node' and 'fc-title' elements while binding, e.g. [$(elem).attr('data-id', 4180) or $(elem).data('id', 4180)], it will become easy to compare both ids

Comment: thx - i just changed `split('One Way')[0]` to `split(')')[0]` so it includes the id too and it works. If you update the answer ill mark it as accepted